# Is there a way to list of all the Index/Queries who has FAST Option given to it ? TIA

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find out which queries an index has FAST Option Given to it. SO far not successful. Appreciate the help on any suggestion and advice.

Comment: What is this `FAST` option for indexes, it's not in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15? There is an `OPTION(FAST` for queries, not related to indexes at all

Comment: Yeap, I have got my question clarified. Thank you @Charlieface 
I had a misunderstanding on this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.